# How do I set my user password on my Google Cloud Ubuntu instance?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, webmin, ubuntu-15.10

I have started an Ubuntu 15.10 instance on Google Cloud and installed Webmin as per here:

http://www.webmin.com/deb.html

Webmin has been installed successfully and I can see the login page in my browser window, however I need to type my username along with my password with sudo level access to login and start using Webmin.

I've used the SSH via the browser window so have never set a password for any sort of access to the root.

Does anyone know how to set a password for myself to login as a sudo user on my instance?

Answer (score 18):

Okay, I figured it out.  I was looking at the permissions menu in Google Cloud, but it was as simple as changing the root password in Linux by typing: `sudo passwd`

Comment: Im getting using username root, authentication failed.

Answer (score 4):

it's working for me

```
vfa_gianglt@instance-1:~$ sudo -i
root@instance-1:~# sudo bash
root@instance-1:~# sudo passwd root
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
root@instance-1:~# cd /root
root@instance-1:~#
```